# iPad running iPhone app stops responding when UIImagePickerController is closed (using cocos2d)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

Okay, so I'm a little confused about how to use the ipad image picker.  I have 2 apps.  One is an HD version built just for ipads.  The other is a regular version built for iPhones (which have to be compatible with iPads).  The iPad works fine when using the HD version and the iPhone works fine when using the non-HD version.  However, when I'm using the iPad with the non-HD version, the camera roll pops up just like it should, but my scene stops responding.  It's almost like the scene is paused or something.

First, I call the picker in an in-app purchase method...

```
UIImagePickerController *picker    = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    NSLog(@"UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad-Does not get called in non-HD version");
    _popover = [[NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController") alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    [_popover setDelegate:self];

    CGSize winsize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    [_popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(winsize.width,winsize.height) animated:NO];

    [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0,0,10,10)  inView:[[CCDirector sharedDirector]openGLView]
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"iPhone");
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    RootViewController *vc = delegate.viewController;

    [vc presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{

    }];

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:picker.view];
}
```

I check to see if the device is an iPad or an iPhone.  If the device is an iPad, I use the popover method to show the camera roll.  Then I close the picker with...

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

```
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
// newImage is a UIImage do not try to use a UIImageView
newImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
newCenterpiece= [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    NSLog(@"UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad--Does not get called in non-HD version");
    [_popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

else
{
    // Dismiss UIImagePickerController and release it
    NSLog(@"[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];)");
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];
    [picker.view removeFromSuperview];

}

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];...
```

I added the startAnimation and resume lines just to see if that was causing my issues, but that doesn't appear to be the case.  After the picker closes, the scene just sits there.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know why this works, but it does.  If I add

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
```

In the in-app purchase method, the code works beautifully.